# Publish over CIFS Plugin

Tags: jenkins, cifs

I am using “Publish over CIFS Plugin”. Test Configuration gives me success messages , I am using it under Post build step in job as “Send build artifact to a Windows share”. Logs just shows:

```
CIFS: Connecting from host [--------]
CIFS: Connecting with configuration [WebSites] ...
CIFS: Disconnecting configuration [WebSites] ...
CIFS: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My job configuration is like this:

```
Source Files: publish
Remove prefix: publish
Remote directory: CCDEVWEB0/FIRECOM/DEVELOPMENT
```

Configuration system:

```
Publish over CIFS -> CIFS Share: 
name: Websites,
Hostname:srvdes3,
username:-----,
password: ----,
Share: WebStites.
```

(The test configuration is successful)

It always transfer 0 files.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

I have publish in my workspace. (workspace/publish)

And development is in my server (CCDEVWEB0/FIRECOM/DEVELOPMENT)

**SOLVED:**
In this case the problem was my job configuration. It should be like this:

```
Source Files: publish/*.*
Remove prefix: publish/
Remote directory: CCDEVWEB0/FIRECOM/DEVELOPMENT
```

(I had problems sending all files together so I had to send them folder by folder)

Comment: Please add the configuration in Jenkins.

Comment: Publish over CIFS ->                                                                                         
CIFS Share:                                                                                                                  name: Websites,                                                                   
Hostname:srvdes3, username:-----, password: ----, Share: WebStites. The test configuration is successful

Comment: Thx. Please edit your question. Where's the `publish` and `development` coming from?

Comment: Thank you Stephen. My problem here is fixed

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that this question can be marked as solved. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

In this case the problem was my job configuration. It should be like this:

```
Source Files: publish/*.*
Remove prefix: publish/
Remote directory: CCDEVWEB0/FIRECOM/DEVELOPMENT
```

(I had problems sending all files together so I had to send them folder by folder)

Comment: Is "CCDEVWEB0" a sub directory, or the shared directory? It seems that the first level is not considered to be in the remote directory, is it?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain all the nested folders and files in the source directory, you can fill the source files input like this

`publish/**`

Even you can add more sources separated by a comma, like this:

`publish/**, secondsource/*.css`

to add all the css files in secondsource/

If you need more information about these patterns, read [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)